# Place Div behind all other Div's using 960.gs

Tags: css, html, 960.gs

I am struggling to get my footer to go behind all the other content on my page.  What I have so far is here: {page removed}

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: define behind a little bit more. are you referring to z-index?

Comment: There is an image anchored to the footer (tree).  I would like that image to be under all of the content on the page.

Comment: You mean the giant tree at the bottom? If that's all the content on top, wouldn't it pretty much be invisible? (That's a pretty sexy website, by the way.)

Comment: Most of it won't be seen but enough will to make it worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if I'm missing the point, but why not just add that image to the background of the body element and just set it to align bottom center.

ie.

```
body{
   background:url(treepic.png) no-repeat center bottom #787066;
}
```

If you don't want to do it that way you could always add a negative margin-top to the footer_background of 782 (eg height of image).

eg.

```
footer_background{
   margin-top:-782;
}
```

Let me know if these aren't what you were looking for.

Sam

Comment: No, you weren't missing anything - I had been creating this site for too many hours and couldn't see the obvious.  It worked beautifully.  Thank you!!!!